# How to fix "400 Bad Request Bad filename" error

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I built an application in MVC 4 a few months ago and configured it through IIS at that time it worked perfectly but now when i call it through any browser then it gives me error in pink screen as

```
400 Bad Request
Bad filename

micro_httpd
```

and one thing more i cannot access any other site e.g google or Facebook from that machine and receiving same message in browser.

i searched it on google (using other machine) but didn't find any solution...

kindly help me. what should i do...?

Comment: there is no one who has any idea about this....?

Comment: Its some **firewall** setting. If `FB` and `google` are not accessible then your system is blocking the sites from being displayed. Check with other systems where all other sites work!